# Is it possible to expose a LAN machine on the internet even with a shared WAN IP?

Tags: networking, router, ip, lan

The IP I receive from the ISP (WAN side of my router) is a private one so I know the public IP (which I can see with "What's my IP") is shared. I can't ask the ISP for a personal public IP.

I want to expose one of my LAN devices on the internet. I don't really care if my public IP is static or not.

The consensus from my searches seems to be that this is not possible. Is it? Or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, because you're not in control of the device that has the public IP address.

Features like routing, "DMZ", and/or "port forwarding" on your router rely on the router itself already being able to receive the packets. In other words, it cannot "pull" connections in; it can only forward what it receives.

So if the public IP address is shared, then there's no way for anyone to send packets to your network specifically. (Technically the ISP would also be able to set up "port forwarding" for customers, but in practice no ISPs do that.)

Your only options are:

1. Use some kind of proxy or VPN tunnel, effectively "borrowing" the tunnel server's public address. It's possible to set up a personal VPN server to forward connections across the tunnel into your home network (as long as the "outer" VPN connection stays up). Some commercial VPN services also offer incoming connections, and there are services that will proxy just HTTP/HTTPS.

   (If it's for your own access only, then you don't even need a complex setup – just connect to your VPN from outside, and through the VPN to home.)
2. Check whether the ISP provides IPv6 access. Many now do; this would allow every device in your network to have its own public IPv6 address and receive incoming connections. (Though of course only from IPv6-capable clients; you'd still need some kind of proxy for IPv4-only clients.)

Comment: Thank you. I see the light with 1.